# Find eigenvalues, kernel and Image of an Orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, orthogonal-matrices, projection

Let $V$ be a Vector space with inner product and $U$ a subspace. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection over $U$. Find eigenvalues, kernel and Image of $P$.

I know I have to consider the special cases of $U=\{0\}$ and $U=V$. But I don't understand How to make the general case.

Comment: Try to visualize this in two dimensions where $U$ is the x-axis. Can you see the kernel (i.e. which vectors are projected to $0$) and the range? Then generalize.

As for the eigenvalues it depends on what you've learned. This is easy if you've learned about the minimal polynomial of an operator. Otherwise you could find a good basis of $V$ where $P$ has a simple form.

Comment: What is the image of an element of $U$? What is the image of an element of $U^\perp$? The answers give you two possible eigenvalues for $P$.

Answer (score 0):

"*An orthogonal projection has spectrum $\,\sigma(P)=\{0,1\}$,
if $P$ is neither zero ($\iff\ker P=V)\,$ nor equal to the identity
($\iff\ker P=\{0\}),\:\ldots\,$*"
could become a complete answer, but.

Searching this site for $\:$ *projection kernel image $\:$* yields many$^\text{many}$ hits, amongst them the following sorted-by-age-almost-dozen,  and you are invited to browse thru:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/251575/316749
- [Show that the direct sum of a kernel of a projection and its image create the originating vector space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/261704/316749)
- [About projection of linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/380945/316749)
- [Prove projection is self adjoint if and only if kernel and image are orthogonal complements](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/584379/316749)
- [Projection operator image and kernell](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/731350/316749)
- [Decomposition of the image of a projection.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1176842/316749)
- [Describe the image and kernel of a projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1449724/316749)
- [Kernel and Image of an orthogonal projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1851552/316749)
- [Vector space as direct sum of kernel and image](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2038575/316749)
- [Orthogonal projection on the image of a linear operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2331125/316749)
- [Finding the image and kernel of an orthogonal projection.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2668559/316749)