# Explain why every vector in $S$ is an eigenvector, and so is every vector in $S^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection-matrices

If $P$ is the matrix that projects $R^n$ onto a subspace $S$, explain why every vector in $S$ is an eigenvector, and so is every vector in $S^{\perp}$. What are the eigenvalues (Note the connection to $P^2 = P$, which means that $λ^2 = λ$ .)

I feel like I'm missing something from the question and therefore have no idea where to begin.

The only thing I can think of to get started is that if $S$ is a proper subspace of $R^n$ then, by the Invertible Matrix Theorem, 0 is an eigenvalue which also holds since $0^2=0$ from the given hint.

This is Review Question 5.6 Linear Algebra and Its Applications Fourth Edition by Gilbert Strang

Comment: Would this in-site reference
[Find eigenvalues, kernel and Image of an Orthogonal projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3014373/316749)
be helpful for you?

Comment: If $\lambda^2=\lambda$, then $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$, so $\lambda(\lambda-1)=0$. That means the only possible eigenvalues of $P$ are $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=1$.

Comment: The problem is incomplete/incorrect as stated. There is no unique matrix that project "onto a subspace $S$". For example, both $P_1\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right)$ and $P_2\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&-1\\0&0\end{array}\right)$ are matrices that project $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $S=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. But while $S^{\perp}$ is the eigenspace of $P_1$ corresponding to $0$, for $P_2$ we have $P_2(0,1)^t = (-1,0)$, so $S^{\perp}$ does not consist of eigenvectors of $P_2$. You need to specify that $P$ is an *orthogonal* projection.

Answer (score 2):

As someone else stated, this works for an orthogonal projection. Think about it geometrically. Let $\bf{v}\in S$. Then the projection  of $\bf{v}$ onto $S$ is just $\bf{v}$ itself. Thus $P\bf{v}$ $=\bf{v}$ $=1\bf{v}$, so $\bf{v}$ is an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda =1$.
Similarly, if $\bf{u}\in S^\bot$, then the projection of $\bf{u}$ onto $S$ is $0$. So $P\bf{u}$ $=\bf{0}$ $=0\bf{u}$, so $\bf{u}$ is an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda =0$.